# How to setup my server exe keep running

Tags: c#, windows

I have a server process which is deployed now, and I want to keep my server running.
In case, if that process crashed by some means, either some exception or any other technical flow, then I need it to be restart again.

For this, I have created another process which keep checking(e.g, every 2 minutes) in processes list for this particular process name, and in case, if not found, it will start that process.

I have implemented this solution, but I know its not a good idea, I believe there must be some better ideas for this job. Can you help me is it best approach, or suggest some better one?

For some limitations, I could not deploy my server process as windows service, its a windows form application.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "server" is a windows form application? In any case, does your code actually have issue where it will occasionally crash?  Or do you need a watchdog app just for the sake of unanticipated crashes?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post any code, but you mentioned "keep checking the processes list every two minutes".  I think a better solution would be to have your watchdog process just be the parent process.  It would call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to launch your EXE as a child process.  Then do a WaitForSingleObject on the child process handle.  As soon as [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns (signaling that the child process has exited), it would just restart it.

The .Net equivalents of CreateProcess and WFSO are [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) and [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx).

Comment: Thanks selbie, I think have to go with windows service option. But I find your idea interesting too, if you could provide any sort of tutorial or supporting material to demonstrate the concept. I would use it in some other scenerio.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the solution is far from optimal. Windows services has automatic restart.

In your case I would start your watch dog process from windows task scheduler to avoid problems if your watch dog dies.

Comment: +1 for watchdog via scheduler - no need to have this as a constantly running process

Comment: But you can't display a user interface from a Windows Service. Presumably, this is the "limitation" that he mentions in the question.

Comment: I made a guess that the problems with running a service was on some permissions part or similar, not the requirement of actually having a user interface.

Comment: yes exactly 'User Interface' is the limitation, which required at the time. but I think the idea is right, have to switch for Windows Service option ultimately.